# How to play videos embedded on other sites in Phonegap Android app

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

I have seen multiple questions regarding this on StackOverflow but never an answer specific to my situation. I built an android app using Phonegap. In the app users are able to click links that direct them to webpages for different businesses. I have the links opening in a new window using `window.open('http://...', '_blank');` , that way they can close the window and go back to the app when they are done browsing. (so essentially an in app browser)

These businesses have youtube videos on their pages and when you click to play them they will not open. I see that there is a [plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) that can be used to solve this, however because I am not opening these videos in a webview (they are just embeded in the linked webpages) I am not sure how to get them to work.

I get the following notifications in the LogCat:

```
06-11 13:35:54.880: E/libEGL(1441): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

06-11 13:35:54.880: D/MediaPlayer(1441): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am using the InAppBrowser to view these web pages. Within the webpages the YouTube videos are embedded as iFrames. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compiling in Phonegap build and now everything functions as it should.